# Clik "Go" on pop-up page with Selenium while creating table in phpmyadmin Java

Tags: java, selenium, phpmyadmin, webdriver

I'm novice at `Selenium WD`. I'm trying to create table with `phpmyadmin`.
During this process I receive pop-up window with `"Add Index"`.
Please give me solution , or tutorial, how I can do this.
[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can find your button using it's text and simply `click()` as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() = 'Go']")).click();
```

P.S. For the future. You should read documentation and make some attempts in resolving your issue by yourself before posting new ticket. Also make sure you provide with your `Java` code and problem description as well as additional details, e.g. `HTML` code sample, that might help answerer to solve your problem